# Preventing more validator

Tags: validation, phalcon

How to stop more validator when other validator on the same field fails?

If following code I do not want Email validator executed when the email is empty.

```
$v=new Phalcon\Validation();

$v->add('email',new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf(['field'=>'email']));
$v->add('email',new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email(['field'=>'email']));

var_dump($v->validate([]));
```

How prevent validation of null fields? I following code I want validation only when an email is set.

```
$v=new Phalcon\Validation();

$v->add('email',new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf(['field'=>'email']));

var_dump($v->validate([]));
```

Actually I use `Class Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator` but the examples use `Class Phalcon\Validation\Validator`. I hoe the answer be same for both.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there is no way to stop the validation in Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator, in the Phalcon\Validation case, you can pass 'cancelOnFail' as parameter to indicate that it must stop the validation chain if the validator with that parameter fails:

```
$v->add('email',new PresenceOf(['field'=>'email', 'cancelOnFail' => true]));
$v->add('email',new \Email(['field'=>'email']));
```

Comment: I hope we see a single reusable validation class in future.

Comment: How prevent validation of empty fields?